JWT with PS256 signing algorithm
We have a use case where we need to authenticate with Netsuite application and the authentication request structure is mentioned here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_162755359851.html
This is a JWT bases authentication and I have formed the JWT request structure as per this documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_162790605110.html
I have two questions to ask

Do we need to set the JWT header explicitly while preparing JWT request in apex code using Auth.JWT class? I believe not, since it internally takes care of setting the JWT header. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

If we look at the alg parameter in the JWT header in above document, it has defined set of algorithms and the Netsuite guy has asked me to set alg as PS256 in the JWT header. But how do we set that if we don't set JWT header in Salesforce explicitly? Also does Salesforce use RS256 by default for alg parameter? If yes, does that mean it won't work?


The reason of asking these questions is because I'm getting invalid_client error when trying to generate access token from Salesforce using jwt method. If I use same vales through postman it works fine. So I suspect there is something wrong with the certificate which is being used in this authentication
Thanks a lot!

2 : No. it's RS256 only (Auth.JWS does the signing).  https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PzOtKUAV/jwt-signing-using-rsassapss

Thanks a lot. Is there any workaround for this? Can we not create JWT request without using Auth.JWS so that I can set the alg param explicitly to PS256 in the JWT request header

You can create your own JWT with whatever header you want but you won't be able to compute the signature with PS256 since this crypto scheme is not natively supported by Crypto class. You'll have to do this outside of Apex.
